# iOS bag with input type="text"

Tags: html, ios, css, bag

I'm create a web form, that has one custom input field with type "text".

CSS looks like

```
input {
height: 39px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
background: #000000 url(../img/search-bg-white.png) no-repeat 95% center;
border: none;
padding: 0 50px 0 10px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

When I tap on it at iPhone 6 all elements are desapiare exluding form elements without this input

And the result is http://gyazo.com/790da935bbfc946420cd37a24b2302db and I don't understand what to do

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a host of disappearing elements, weird scroll behaviors, and keyboard issues happen on various iOS 8+ webview applications. The issue appears to be related to embedding inputs inside scrollable elements, or a combination of scrollable elements with some other element on the page--I've not been able to isolate it beyond that. (The behaviors I see don't always occur on a page with inputs, so @Josh Crozier's answer above would work 100% of the time for my case.)

The solution I found was to wait until after the page was rendered, then adjust the z-index of the scrolling element, which I hypothesize is forcing the rendering engine to repaint the layer.

To test whether this works for you, try loading the page on an iPhone 6 connected to your developer Mac by USB, and inspecting the page in Safari. Just before you tap into the input field, use the Safari dev tools to adjust the z-index of the parent scrollable container (or to add a z-index if not present). Then tap into the field and see if that continues to be a problem. If the problem doesn't occur, you'll have to attach some JavaScript to your page to force a repaint/relayout/reswizzle of the page after it has rendered.

Good luck. :\

Comment: Thx for your answer. Not only the input element disapeare, there are all DOM elements exclude form inputs. And i haven't Mac )

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for this bug. I put on body element css property -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and when I removed it - all works fine.